# Magento2 city dropdown in address field

Tags: checkout, dropdown, magento2, city

How can I convert the city input field to drop-down and make dependent it on region?
City will be depend on the selected region. So when user select region, dependent city will be populated in city dropdown.

Comment: extend the block and change the field and its dependency

Comment: have you found any solution ,i have to same.

Comment: you can find an answer here, https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/121659/31830

Comment: If you are looking for an extension, there's one - https://www.magepsycho.com/magento2-region-city-dropdown-manager.html